php.ini Path Disagreement
There are two tools commonly used to identify the configuration file path of php.ini. But in my environment, Ubuntu running Apache and PHP 8.2.21, the two tools disagree.
From my browser, running a php which invokes phpinfo() yields:
/etc/php/8.2/apache2
But from the Ubuntu terminal, running php --ini yields:
/etc/php/8.2/cli
Why the difference? And which is the correct path?
Thanks.

You are running 2 different versions of php, so each is showing the ini file that it is using.

Thanks, Nigel, but I'm unclear. How would I be running 2 different versions of php? How would I reconfigure my environment to use only a single version of php?

They're both correct. @NigelRen doesn't mean two separate numeric versions, but two different contexts. One is for the Apache module and the other is for the CLI. This allows you to have two different configurations, depending on how PHP is invoked.

Thanks, Alex. I am just learing about PHP CLI now. I don't anticipate using it. In a production environment, is there any reason I should shut down PHP CLI, or should I just leave it be?

I can't possibly answer that for you. It's generally useful for running cron jobs, message queue workers, and tools that only get invoked manually, like commands registered with Symfony's bin/console or Laravel's php artisan tools.

Much appreciated. I'll just leave it be.

I'm actually glad you're asking this question in this direkt form: Is this a disagreement?
Let's see the observations again:

From my browser, running a php which invokes phpinfo() yields:
/etc/php/8.2/apache2
But from the Ubuntu terminal, running php --ini yields:
/etc/php/8.2/cli

So far so clear. Even if the paths each in themselves would be different, we can clearly see that PHP running in the webserver is using a different php.ini file than PHP running on the command line.
Now for what you ask specifically, I start with the easier to answer question, answer it shortly, then the other question and answer it shortly as well, and then add a bit more.

Which is the correct path?

Both paths are correct.

Why the difference?

Because, that are two different PHP configurations, and in your case (which is common) two different PHP SAPIs: One for the webserver and one for the terminal.

And now a little bit of background:
PHP is not that different as other software packages: There is a (main) program (the PHP interpreter as a binary) which can run in and with different configurations, e.g. the "disagreeing" php.ini filenames.
We like your question because doing own research comparing things and working with the differences is a key tool. And it's much fun if you have a Linux box to do this on.
PHP is also pretty similar to many other softwares, and that is, it is literally running in an environment, and its configuration and behaviour can be influenced by it. If you'd like to learn more about that, one such parameter is named PHPRC and it contains the path to the php.ini filename. Just mentioning, it's not the only way to specify that file.
Read more in the PHP Manual: Runtime Configuration but also dig into the concept of the different PHP SAPIs (Server Application Programming Interface, e.g. php_sapi_name(), What is SAPI and when would you use it?). The PHP SAPIs are something that is quite specific to PHP and not all programs have something similar.

I appreciate the comprehensive answer.

@snixdata: Thanks! Is there anything specific you're interested in? Perhaps in the light of your current configuration?

Thank you, @harke, I think I'm good for now, but I'll reach out if I need more help. Take care.
